# SetState not working with listview.builder

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, setstate

i have some code here for a an application chat screen. This specific chat screen is used to chat with a bot. The bot is supposed to send a message after each message by the user. The list of messages to be sent by the bot is stored in messageStrings. I'm using a listview.builder to populate the UI with new messages added in the List messages.

I'm using setstate to add new messages, but the UI Isn't getting updated with the new messages. This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/chats.dart';

class ReportPage extends StatefulWidget {
  BuildContext context;
  ReportPage(this.context);
  @override
  _ReportPageState createState() => _ReportPageState();
}

class _ReportPageState extends State<ReportPage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(Object context) {
    TextEditingController messageContoller = new TextEditingController();

    //The first two messages by the bot are already added to the List
    List<ChatMessage> messages = [
    ChatMessage(messageContent: "Message 1", messageType: "receiver"),
    ChatMessage(messageContent: "Message 2", messageType: "receiver"),
  ];
  int messageIndex = 0;
  //The next messages that are to be added to the list after a response from the user
  List<String> messageStrings = ["Message 3", "Message 4","Message 5",];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(children: [
          Container(
            width: 35,
            height: 35,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/police.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Text("CFB bot"),
        ]),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: messages.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: (messages[index].messageType == "receiver"
                        ? Alignment.topLeft
                        : Alignment.topRight),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: (messages[index].messageType == "receiver"
                            ? Colors.grey.shade200
                            : Colors.blue[200]),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Text(
                        messages[index].messageContent,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                height: 60,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.lightBlue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Write message...",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            border: InputBorder.none),
                            controller: messageContoller,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        String message = messageContoller.text;
                        setState(() {
                          messages.add(ChatMessage(messageContent: message, messageType: "sender"));              
                          messages.add(ChatMessage(messageContent: messageStrings[messageIndex], messageType: "receiver"));                                        
                        });
                        messageIndex++;
                        for(int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
                          print(messages[i].messageContent);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.send,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 18,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      elevation: 0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly using `List.add` try changing the reference of your `messages` to a completely new `List` as well, like this,

```
messages = [
    ...messages,
    ChatMessage(messageContent: message, messageType: "sender"),
    ChatMessage(messageContent: messageStrings[messageIndex], messageType: "receiver")
];
```

Why this works is that now, you are destroying the old reference of the `messages` and assigning it a completely new reference of `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and it's still not updating the UI. is there any other way i can overcome this issue?

Comment: That is just not possible.

Comment: So you are saying, even if you change anything inside your setState, your UI is not rebuilding ?

Comment: put a `print` statement inside your build function to check if it is getting called or not.

Comment: Sorry mate, the issue was that i put the List inside the build function. So, it was getting reset each time. I put it in the State Class and it's working fine now. Thanks for the help

Comment: glad to have helped :)